# Is Brownian motion a semimartingale?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

I have read an article about semimartingales on Wikipedia and it says that: *"A Brownian motion is a semimartingale"*. However, it is hard for me to find any proof of this statement, and I really doubt about its accuracy. Can any one verify if the statement is true, or show me some counter examples if the statement is wrong?

Here is the link of the article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimartingale

Comment: A BM is a martingale...

Comment: More explicitly: all càdlàg martingales, submartingales and supermartingales are semimartingales. BM is a martingale, see e.g.  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820896/532409 or Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brownian Motion is Martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820896/brownian-motion-is-martingale)

Answer (score 5):

A semimartingale $X_t$ is a process that can be written as $$X_t = X_0 + M_t + A_t$$
where $M_t$ is a (local) martingale and $A_t$ is a process of finite variation. In particular, any martingale is a semimartingale, simply by setting $A_t = 0$. Since Brownian motion is a martingale, it is a semimartingale.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the quadratic variation of a Brownian motion $\left(B_t\right)_{t \geq 0}$ is equal to $t$. Thus $[B]_t = t$. Now if we add to the brownian motion another continuous process and of finite variation (denoted as X). Then $B+X$ is also a Brownian motion since its quadratic variation is still $t$. Hence, $B + X + B_0$ is also a Brownian motion (note that $B_0$ is already equal to 0). We can conclude that a Brownian motion is a semimartingale.